# :hover is interfering with child's border

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I have a table with `<tr>`s that, upon hover, dims in brightness. However, when I hover, the children (`<td>`) lose their black border.

the css:

```css
tr:hover {
  filter: brightness(0.7);
}

td {
 border: 0.5px;
 border-color: black;
}
```

what is actually looks like using tailwindcss:

```js
              <tr ... className="hover:brightness-75">
                { row.cells.map(cell => (
                  <td ... className="border-[0.5px] border-black">
                    ...                  
                  </td>
              ))}
              </tr>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `border-separate` ([Border Collapse Utility](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/border-collapse)) and `border-spacing-0` ([Border Spacing Utility](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/border-spacing)) on your `table` element to avoid affecting your border.

##### Tailwind:

```html
<table class="border-separate border-spacing-0 border-[0.5px] border-black">
  <tr class="hover:brightness-75">
    <th class="border-[0.5px] border-black bg-teal-700 p-4 font-bold">Firstname</th>
    <th class="border-[0.5px] border-black bg-teal-700 p-4 font-bold">Lastname</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hover:brightness-75">
    <td class="border-[0.5px] border-black bg-teal-700 p-4 font-bold">Chen</td>
    <td class="border-[0.5px] border-black bg-teal-700 p-4 font-bold">Br</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hover:brightness-75">
    <td class="border-[0.5px] border-black bg-teal-700 p-4 font-bold">Brian</td>
    <td class="border-[0.5px] border-black bg-teal-700 p-4 font-bold">Barry</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[Tailwind-Play link](https://play.tailwindcss.com/Sl547Qj4NQ)

---

##### CSS:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0px 0px;
}
```